# Why does pretty much everything depend on gstreamer phonon backend?

Tags: apt, kde, dependencies, phonon

I’ve just installed and configured a minimal KDE distro based on the Ubuntu 13.04 minimal CD. It’s working really well but I have 1 gripe with it.

After installing kde-plasma-desktop gstreamer was automatically downloaded as the phonon backend, which was fine as I’d just replace it with my usual vlc backend and remove phonon-backend-gstreamer.

So I remove phonon-backend-gstreamer, which gets removed as expected, and I’ve now got autoremove correctly advising me that some gstreamer-* libs are now not required; normal behaviour. But…autoremove is also recommending that it removes Linux-sound-base, alsa-base etc, some were also included that seemed unrelated to me, such as libsoup.

Now I know this is not a major issue, as I don’t *have* to run autoremove, but it’s just bugging me why this is happening.

Why has a gstreamer backend got such a massive dependency list?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

Well, to answer my own question, it doesn't :)

What I completely failed to take into consideration when I asked this question was the important fact that I did a *minimal install* so lots (and I meant *lots*) of things were "automatically" added when I installed kde-plasma-desktop.  Plus the fact that I have no *kubuntu-desktop* or a variant of to keep things like alsa as a dependency.

So I did:

```
sudo apt-get install alsa-base
```

even though I knew it was already installed and that was all that was needed to mark alsa-base as manually installed and voilà!  Autoremove now only wants to remove the no longer required dependencies of gstreamer.